# Jquery enable/disable button based on select option

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to enable or disable a button which is in a form, based on a select (drop down) option which isn't in a form? I don't have any code, I will have it (or not) based on your answer to my question :D

Comment: Yes it is possible. I don't have any answer till I don't see any code.

Comment: No, no, guys, easy, I don't expect you to work for me, just wanted to know is it possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/vZacx/

```
$('#picker').on('change', function() {
    $('#' + $(this).val()).prop('disabled', false)
        .siblings().prop('disabled', true);
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put your code disabling/enabling the button in the change event of the drop down.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe :

```
​$("select")​.on('change', function() {
    $('button').prop('disabled', this.value==='EnabledOptionValue'?false:true);
})​;
```

​
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9xxxu/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var theVal = $(this).val();
  switch(theVal){
    case '0':
      $('#theButton').prop('disabled', true);
      break;
    case '1':
      $('#theButton').prop('disabled', false);
      break;
  }
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XRXR/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#demo_button").button({icons: {secondary: "ui-icon-info"}});
$("#demoSelect").addClass("ui-state-default ui-corner-all");
var demoSelectValue = $("#demoSelect").val();
if (demoSelectValue == "0") {
$("#demo_button").button("disable")
}
$("#demoSelect").change(function(){
if($(this).val() == "0"){
$("#demo_button").button("disable")
}
else {
$("#demo_button").button("enable")
}
});
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="demoSelect" id="demoSelect">
<option value="0">No</option>
<option value="1">Yes</option>
</select>
<button id="demo_button" style="float:right;">button</button>
```

[image: jsFiddle demo]

see [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/portashqipe/dkLtzaua/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Select').change(function(){
    //Some condition
    $('#Button').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```